# How to fix this giltch on ESM for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, esm, ubuntu-pro

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 10 and applied for a free personal subscription to Ubuntu Pro, but when I completed the steps to enable ESM with Ubuntu Pro, it showed as **31/12/99** instead of **31/12/32**, something like that. Please see the screenshot for more info.

[image: The Screenshot]